# How to make a pure CSS dropdown list (nav for a website)

Tags: css

Trying to make a pure css dropdown list that works well, and can't find any good resources.

Comment: This [one](http://www.mycssmenu.com/) may help too

Answer (score 6):

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com) is a great resource, here's their take: [Drop-Down Menus, Horizontal Style](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/horizdropdowns/)

Comment: Agreed, A List Apart has some of the best articles out there!

Comment: requires some Javascript to work in IE6, but I'm not sure if there's a way around that

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll be able to find something like what you want at http://css.maxdesign.com.au/index.htm. Sorry if it doesn't work out (but there are quite a lot of different lists...)!

Answer (score 1):

GRC has a [pure CSS menuing system](http://www.grc.com/menudemo.htm) that's freely available.

Comment: And the best part is that it collates the best parts of a lot of the other suggestions. I also trust Steve to have thoroughly tested the code based on his other work.

Answer (score 0):

- [pixelspread: CSS Drop Down Menu](http://pixelspread.com/blog/289/css-drop-down-menu)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of the [Free CSS Drop-Down Menu Framework](http://www.lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/), although [this one](http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/keyboard_friendly_dropdown_menu/default.asp) has great accessibility (support for tab key to navigate the list)

Answer (score 0):

Son of Suckerfish is one of the best

http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/
http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/